# Setting GitHub's 'soft wrap' option to be on by default

Tags: github, default-value, word-wrap

In GitHub's web app, there is a drop down menu to select which line wrap mode you want to edit with.

Is there a way to set this option to 'soft wrap' by default so when I edit a new file, it is already on 'soft wrap'?

[image: soft wrap option in GitHub's web editor]

Answer (score 0):

I landed here in a search for a better GitHub online editing experience. I haven't found a direct answer, but there is a related question which suggests a url tag (not working?) and a Chrome extension, that may have some helpful guidance.

In the meantime, I have posted a more general question and two online tools which have helped me here: [A better online editor for GitHub.com and GitHub Pages?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82573/a-better-online-editor-for-github-com-and-github-pages)

Comment: Link to other question is not working

Comment: @Joel, well the mods hid and then deleted the post, in their infinite wisdom, or probably because "We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more" which i find bizarre for a site about programming. I'll try to find another SE site where this is allowed, because oddly enough, I'm running into this problem again, and was going to post a question about it because I forgot I had already.. so thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Joel, I just made a question at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82573/a-better-online-editor-for-github-com-and-github-pages and updated the link. I'll copy over the answers that were posted.